# How to install Windows XP MBR from FreeDOS

Tags: windows, windows-xp, partitioning, mbr, freedos

I accidentally corrupted my Windows XP installation (i use it for programm testing). Luckily, i had copied the installation files before. Now i made a partition via FreeDOS, and i copied Windows XP files to it. But i know that it wont boot without the MBR. I have all the files required to boot: `autoexec.bat, config.sys, io.sys, msdos.sys, and ntldr.` So i wanted to know how i can install the Windows XP MBR to the partition with using FreeDOS.

Answer (score 0):

Freedos should include the [fdisk](http://help.fdos.org/en/hhstndrd/base/fdisk.htm) utility, which has the switch `/cmbr DRIVENUMBER` and `/mbr DRIVENUMBER`.

```
  MBR (Master Boot Record) modification:
    /AMBR [drive#]  Writes the MBR stored in the "boot.mbr" file to 'drive#'.
    /BMBR [drive#]  Writes the BOOTEASY MBR to 'drive#'.
    /CMBR [drive#]  Creates the MBR.
    /MBR  [drive#]  Writes the standard MBR to 'drive#'.
    /SMBR [drive#]  Saves the current MBR on 'drive#', into a file called
                    "boot.mbr".
    /RMBR [drive#]  Removes the MBR from 'drive#'.
```

I believe using fdisk without a switch should help you find the drive number you need.